# arp spoofing on ni myrio

Tags: kali-linux, arp-spoofing

I created a traffic light system using NI myRio and LabVIEW,
Now I want to arp spoof this system

what I did is using arpspoof command on another PC that runs kali linux,
The ip address are:

192.168.2.15 myRio

192.168.2.9  my computer that runs labview

192.168.2.19 the attacking PC

192.168.2.1  the gateway

Then when I wrote these command after enabling ip forwarding, I couldn't catch any packet !

arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.2.15 192.168.2.1

arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.15

Then I tried to do the arpspoofing using myRio IP and my IP

arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.2.15 192.168.2.9

arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.2.9 192.168.2.15

and I was able to catch all the packets, but for some reason when I stop the attack, myRio lose the connection to labview and it stops working

anyone have any clue about the reason?